# Pythonic way of changing quantities based on rule in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:
posdf:

```
          tradingsymbol quantity   symbol
0  BRITANNIA20SEP3850CE     -200   BRITANNIA
1  BRITANNIA20SEP3900CE     -200   BRITANNIA
```

I change the `quantity` to absolute:

posdf['quantity'] = abs(posdf['quantity'])

eqdf:

```
        symbol  qty
0   BRITANNIA  225
```

I `merge` them:

```
posdf = pd.merge(posdf, eqdf, how='outer', on='symbol')
```

And get:

```
          tradingsymbol quantity  qty
0  BRITANNIA20SEP3850CE     -200  225
1  BRITANNIA20SEP3900CE     -200  225
```

What I want to get:

```
           tradingsymbol quantity  qty  symbol
0  BRITANNIA20SEP3850CE     200  200   BRITANNIA
1  BRITANNIA20SEP3900CE     200  25    BRITANNIA
```

i.e. get the `qty` column to be equal to `quantity` and if not enough `qty` then the remainder or 0.

The column `qty` to have a number equal to `quantity` if `qty` from `eqdf` is higher than `quantity`.

If the `qty` is higher and there are more than 1 `tradingsymbol` for a symbol fill the left over quantity into the next.

If there is no `qty` left fill with 0.

I hope this clarifies a bit more.

There are hundreds of different `symbols`,`qty` and quantities.

I would be able to loop through it fill quantities, looking for advice on whether this can be done in a more `pandas` friendly way?

Comment: Pls explain better what are you trying to do

Comment: @gtomer just added it to the question. get the `qty` column to be equal to `quantity` and if not enough `qty` then the remainder or 0.

Comment: Sorry. Still not clear. Equal to what? Reminder from what?

Comment: @Sid, need more real examples for better answering this question.

Comment: Changing things in the question.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR** - rethink your data structure maybe?

I don't think merging is the way to go. Basically the way I think of this is you want to keep some kind of running "balance" at a "point in time". So instead what you want to say is "at the start of the time period I have $X" and I want to know if I keep making these transactions what is the resulting balance.

So the way I think of this is we instead want to use `pd.concat`, and then a cumulative sum, with the condition that we can't go negative.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

posdf = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "tradingsymbol": ["BRITANNIA20SEP3850CE", "BRITANNIA20SEP3900CE"],
        "quantity": [-200, -200],
        "symbol": ["BRITANNIA", "BRITANNIA"]
    }
)

eqdf = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "symbol": ["BRITANNIA"],
        "quantity": [225]
    }
)

alldf = pd.concat([eqdf, posdf]).sort_values(by="tradingsymbol", na_position="first")
```

Output of `alldf`:

```
      symbol  quantity         tradingsymbol
0  BRITANNIA       225                   NaN
0  BRITANNIA      -200  BRITANNIA20SEP3850CE
1  BRITANNIA      -200  BRITANNIA20SEP3900CE
```

From here, we can do `cumsum` with `numpy.maximum` to prevent it going below zero.

```
In []: np.maximum(alldf['quantity'].cumsum(), 0)                                                                         
Out[]: 
0    225
0     25
1      0
Name: quantity, dtype: int64
```

Then putting it together becomes trivial exercise of getting the targetted output.

```py
alldf['qty'] = np.maximum(alldf['quantity'].cumsum(), 0).shift() - np.maximum(alldf['quantity'].cumsum(), 0)
```

Output

```py
In []: alldf                                                                                                             
Out[]: 
      symbol  quantity         tradingsymbol    qty
0  BRITANNIA       225                   NaN    NaN
0  BRITANNIA      -200  BRITANNIA20SEP3850CE  200.0
1  BRITANNIA      -200  BRITANNIA20SEP3900CE   25.0
```